# empty values in SonataAdminBundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata

I learn SonataAdminBundle with this tutorial:
http://sftuts.com/doc/jobeet/en/the-admin-generator

but instead of:

[image]

I have empty values:

[image]

Also in form, I have only submit button, but if I click this button then I have error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'type' cannot be null
```

Maybe is better tutorial for SonataAdminBundle?

**EDIT:**

```
<?php

//src/SfTuts/JobeetBundle/Admin/CategoryAdmin.php

namespace SfTuts\JobeetBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;

class CategoryAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected $list = array(
        'id' => array('identifier' => true),
        'name',
    );
    protected $form = array(
        'name',
    );
    protected $filter = array(
        'name',
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you share your Admin class' code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read this piece of documentation. Your version of the tutorial could be outdated. 
http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/index.html

Try this code:

```
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
class CategoryAdmin extends Admin
{
    /**
     * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper $formMapper
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('name')
            ;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper $datagridMapper
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('name');
    }

    /**
     * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper $listMapper
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->add('id')
            ->addIdentifier('name');
    }
}
```